# Would a question elsewhere be a better fit on space.se?

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/179395/what-topics-does-the-kerbal-space-program-touch-upon-during-game-play) about the Kerbal Space Program video game over on Arqade, and it was not well received. I had a lot of trouble conveying to the community there that I was interested in what KSP could teach a player in terms of real-world concepts utilized in space exploration and rocket science. I expected answers as a list - and possibly with brief summaries if appropriate - to allow for further research as opposed to in-depth explanations. After 4 down votes and a lot of back and forth on clarity, the only answer I got was a high-level description of the overall game-play instead of the concepts and techniques necessary to operate a successful space flight in the simulation. Two questions:

1. Would that question be a better fit here and on topic?
2. If yes, what's the best way to handle moving the question over?

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes. Understanding the physics behind KSP is definitely on topic here, and there's already been a few questions asked with regard to the physics behind here. However, the question you seem likely to ask is an extremely broad one. I would encourage you to ask more specific questions. See [kerbal-space-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kerbal-space-program)

In particular, I think you'll find the answers to your question at [How realistic is Kerbal Space Program?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4505/25)

Comment: That was a great question to read. I'm curious as to how my question would be broad. As I reference in the question and more specifically reference in some comments, [this](http://what-if.xkcd.com/107/) question on [what-if?](http://what-if.xkcd.com/) references depressed trajectories as a concept KSP players would be familiar with. I was hoping to get a list of other concepts KSP players would be familiar with. That list should most certainly be finite, but I wasn't expecting anything too detailed or exhaustive.

Comment: Asking about a specific trajectory and referencing KSP would be an excellent question. Asking about other types of trajectories might be too broad, but it might work, I'd have to see the question.

Comment: I'll try to see if there's a way to make it concise. I'm just looking for a list of topics that pertain to the game to do further research on rather than attempting to solve a problem. Is there a way to migrate the question across or is my best option is to close the one on Arqade and repost it here?